# Multi-Geo with Developer Account

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, multi-geo

Can I able to use Multi-Geo using the Developer account ? if yes pls give elaborate the steps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my information Multi-Geo is not possible with Developer Program.

You can find out what is included in developer subscription at below link:

[What's included in the developer subscription?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/developer-program/microsoft-365-developer-program-faq#what-s-included-in-the-developer-subscription-)

Comment: Thanks man :) could you please suggest me to get a multi-geo subscription which is needed for my product that im developing.

Comment: Please go through [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/enterprise/plan-for-multi-geo?view=o365-worldwide) link which will guide you with all steps